# Telegram PHP create keyboard

Tags: php, keyboard, bots, telegram

someone could help me to fix the problem in this code?
I would like to have 3 buttons in the telegram bot. 
This is the execute.php file, if in the parameters I put reply_markup doesn't work.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);

if(!$update)
{
  exit;
}

$message = isset($update['message']) ? $update['message'] : "";
$messageId = isset($message['message_id']) ? $message['message_id'] : "";
$chatId = isset($message['chat']['id']) ? $message['chat']['id'] : "";
$firstname = isset($message['chat']['first_name']) ? $message['chat']['first_name'] : "";
$lastname = isset($message['chat']['last_name']) ? $message['chat']['last_name'] : "";
$username = isset($message['chat']['username']) ? $message['chat']['username'] : "";
$date = isset($message['date']) ? $message['date'] : "";
$text = isset($message['text']) ? $message['text'] : "";

$text = trim($text);
$text = strtolower($text);

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$response = '';
$encodedMarkup = '';

$list=array("A", "B", "C");
$response="Choose:";
global $bottoken;
$replyMarkup = array(
    'keyboard' => list,
);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);

$parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId, 'text' => $response, 'reply_markup' => $encodedMarkup);
$parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
echo json_encode($parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
list=array("A", "B", "C");
```

You cannot assign values to a constant. You can only `define()` a constant, e.g.

```
define('list', array('A', 'B', 'C'));
```

Perhaps you mean

```
$list=array("A", "B", "C");
^--
```

instead?

Comment: yes, it was an error in copy/paste. But it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$list = array(array("A", "B", "C"));
$replyMarkup = array("keyboard" => $list,"resize_keyboard" => false,"one_time_keyboard" => false);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);
```